# How to apply django @transaction decorator to celery task

Tags: django, transactions, celery

In my project I use transactions by default. I want to disable them for few celery tasks. But when I use:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.non_atomic_requests

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.non_atomic_requests
@app.task(bind=True, name='my_task')
def tasks_monitor(task):
    m = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    m.value = 5
    m.save()
    time.sleep(40)
```

My celery task is still do transactions. And looks like `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` and `@transaction.atomic_requests` not applying.

**UPD:** Trying to swap order, not working too.
When i disabled `DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = False` it works as expected

Comment: What if you swap the order of the decorators?

Comment: I tried, not working too @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Try using a context manager (`with transaction.non_atomic_requests`) inside the function.

Comment: @stefanw AttributeError at __enter__

Comment: @Arti What is your evidence that your celery task is still using transactions even when you use `@transaction.non_atomic_requests`?

Comment: @Louis when I do loop: ```for x in range(0, 10): m = MyModel.objects.filter(value=4).first()
    m.value = 5 m.save()

Comment: in next iteration I get the same object

Comment: or if I do time.sleep for 2 minutes, and in this time check database, that have old value

Comment: When i disable `DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
` it works as expected

Comment: @Arti Please include in your question the code that launches your celery task and the code that uses the results of the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transaction.non_atomic_requests` is meant to decorate a view, it won't have any effect on a Celery task. But here is the thing: the setting `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` shouldn't have any effect either! The only place it is evaluated in Django is in `core.handlers.base.make_view_atomic`, which wraps views.

Therefore, my assumption is that you run your application with `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` (`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` in older versions of Celery). In this case, the transaction of the view is active. If you set it to `False` and run your tasks in a worker, each DB operation should be autocomitted.

Comment: yes, you were right, I missed `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` and also yes, `transaction.non_atomic_requests` is useless